# List<String> minus List<String>

Tags: java, list

I have following code. In the first i tried to set values in the list called 'unavailable'. 
Next, in the for each I have to  produce a cycle on the list domainStr minus unavailable. How can i do it?

```
public Result execute(List<String> domainsStr) {

        Result result = new Result();       

        try {
            List<String> domains = domainService.findByNames(domainsStr);
            result.setUnavailable(domains);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        for (String domain : domainsStr) {
        ......
        }
        return result;
    }
    public static class Result {

    private List<String> unavailable = new ArrayList<>();


    public List<String> getUnavailable() {
        return unavailable;
    }

    public void setUnavailable(List<String> unavailable) {
        this.unavailable = unavailable;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have to to produce a cycle on the list domainStr minus unavailable.

If I understood correctly, I think you are looking for the [`removeAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#removeAll%28java.util.Collection%29) method :

> Removes from this list all of its elements that are contained in the
>   specified collection (optional operation).

```
domainsStr.removeAll(result.getUnavailable());
for (String domain : domainsStr) {

}
```

If you want to let `domainsStr` unchanged, you can create a temporary list and perfom these operations on it.

Answer (score 7):

[removeAll(Collection c)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#removeAll%28java.util.Collection%29) is the function which would be the most helpful to you. Having said that, this will work properly only if you have the equals method correctly defined for your `Domain` object. In this case it is a `String` so it doesnt matter. But, just to keep it in mind.

so just say, `domainsStr.removeAll(result.getUnavailable());`

Also, if the Result class is static, why the new object creation here?

```
Result result = new Result();
```

This `result.setUnavailable(domains);`
can be changed to 
`Result.setUnavailable(domains);`

Answer (score 1):

```
List<String> tempList = new ArrayList<String>(domainsStr);
tempList.removeAll(result.getUnavailable());
for(String domain : tempList){ 
    .....
```

I put them into a tempt list so you don't lose the items in the domainsStr list.